# Replace all occurrences of character in file

Tags: java, string, replace

Is there a quick way to replace all occurrences of a given character in a file (the whole file at once) for another?

I wonder if this could be done in a global way or something, without reading it line by line.

in my specific case, I want to replace pipes (`|`) for commas (`,`).

Comment: Does this have to be done in Java?  It would be trivial to do `sed -i 's/|/,/g' filename`.

Comment: yeah, must be done in java..

Comment: @filippo did you get it resolved?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yeah I've managed. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply [retrieve the text from the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file) and then use `string.replaceAll("\\|", ",");`

Here is an example using the code from erickson's answer:

> ```
> private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
>   FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
>   try {
>     FileChannel fc = stream.getChannel();
>     MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
>     /* Instead of using default, pass in a decoder. */
>     return Charset.defaultCharset().decode(bb).toString();
>   }
>   finally {
>     stream.close();
>   }
> }
> ```

You can use it like this:

```
String replacedTxt = readFile(path).replaceAll("\\|", ",");
```

Comment: You need to escape the pipe as the string is a regex: `replaceAll("\|", ",")`.

Comment: @SimonC I think it will need `"\\|"` in java other wise it wont compile.

Comment: Don't forget you have to write it back to the file.